# Nextjs, Axios and graphql issue: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: django, docker, next.js, apollo-client, graphene-django

I am making request from nextjs app to django graphql server with the following code.

```
export const loadCategories = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:8000/graphql/",
      data: {
        query: `
          query GET_CATEGORIES{
            categories{
              edges{
                node{
                  id
                  name
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `,
      },
    });

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.detail) {
      const feedbackResponse = error.response.data.detail;
      return feedbackResponse;
    } else if (error.response && error.response.data) {
      const feedbackResponse = error.response.data.feedbackResponse;
      return feedbackResponse;
    } else if (error.request) {
      const feedbackResponse = "Server unavailable";
      return feedbackResponse;
    } else {
      const feedbackResponse = error.message;
      return feedbackResponse;
    }
  }
};
```

In getStaticProps

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  //...............................
  const data = await loadCategories();
  console.log(data);

  return {
    props: {
      response: data,
    },
  };
};
```

Everything works fine in dev mode, but in production after build process I get the following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

I tried to change axios and use Apollo/client but still get the same error

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {

  const { data, error } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query GET_CATEGORIES {
        categories {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  });

  return {
    props: {
      response: data,
    },
  };
};
```

What bothers me is that, when I make the query client side with the code below I get the response  both to dev and production mode.

```
const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(gql`
    query GET_CATEGORIES {
      categories {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);
```

**Can somebody explain me what is happening here?
Why everything works fine in dev mode, but in production mode (After build ) request works only in the client side and failed in getStaticProps ?**

Comment: It works probably when you add this line in next.config.js: domains: ['localhost'].

Comment: Thanks for your response. Means that i replace remotePatterns with domains ?

Comment: You can replace that indeed. If you serve only your own content you can keep domains. If not remotePatterns is recommended, which has also more options like the path you defined. Perhaps it could also be the port. In the docs I see them leaving it away or empty: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#domains

Comment: I tried it but do not work. I don't understand what is happening